# Integration in Julia

Tags: julia, numerical-integration

```
function integration_1(ϕ, St, K, r, τ, vt,θ, κ, σ, ρ)
    hes = heston_C(log(St),vt,t,r,κ*θ,0.5,κ-ρ*σ,ρ,σ,ϕ)
    t = exp(1im*ϕ*log(K))*hes/(1im*ϕ)
    return real(t)
end
```

I want to integrate the function integration_1 with respect to ϕ

Comment: what is `heston_C`? you might want to checkout this: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/numerical-integration-over-given-integral-how-to-do-it-in-julia/14267/3?u=jling